# sort array of associative arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I know this might be duplicate question or there is an answer somewhere here in stackoverflow but i just can't make it work on my code. Here is the sample:

i have the PHP :

```
foreach ($load_image_array as $key) {
    foreach($key as $k) {
      echo "<pre>";
       print_r($k);
      echo "<pre>"; 
    }
  }
```

where when i print_r, it display like so :

```
Array
(
    [upload_id] => 26
    [upload_username] => user1
)
Array
(
    [upload_id] => 23
    [upload_username] => user2
)
Array
(
    [upload_id] => 25
    [upload_username] => user1
)
Array
(
    [upload_id] => 24
    [upload_username] => user2
)
```

I just want to sort it by `[upload_id]`. I tried array_multisort but i can't make it work, any pros can guide me here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**USORT**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Your array elements are array themselves. You can use a custom comparison function.

```
function sort_desc($item1,$item2)
{
    if ($item1['upload_id'] == $item2['upload_id']) return 0;
    return ($item1['upload_id'] < $item2['upload_id']) ? 1 : -1;
}
usort($upload,'sort_desc');
print_r($upload);
```

**OR** you can also use the below a `simplified` version.

```
<?php
   usort($upload, function($a, $b) {
       return $a->integer_property - $b->integer_property;
   });       
?>
```

Comment: function sort_desc($item1,$item2)  
{  
    if ($item1['upload_id'] == $item2['upload_id']) return 0;  
    return ($item1['upload_id'] < $item2['upload_id']) ? 1 : -1;  
}  
  
  foreach ($load_image_array as $key) {  
    foreach($key as $k) {  
      
    }  
  }  

usort($k,'sort_desc');  
echo "<pre>";  
print_r($k);  
echo "<pre>";  
  
This doesn't work :(

Comment: WHats the issue you are facing?.

Comment: The issue might be simple but i cant get it fixed, Message: Illegal string offset 'upload_id'.

Comment: why are doing another foreach inside a foreach... just access print_r($key). If you get this error in future " Its more like your $item1 is not an array and to debug do a var_dump($var) to know more on what data-type you are trying to access...

Comment: ok, i removed another foreach and access the $key and it's kinda working but there is some problem, i have 5 items in the array and after sorting, i only have 3 of them.

Comment: Thanks, i do it like this and it works!
function sort_desc($item1,$item2) { 
  if ($item1['upload_id'] == $item2['upload_id']) return 0; 
  return ($item1['upload_id'] < $item2['upload_id']) ? 1 : -1; 
} 

  $array_list = array();
  foreach ($load_image_array as $key) { 
    foreach ($key as $lol){
      $array_list[] = $lol;
    }
    
  } 
usort($array_list,'sort_desc');
echo "<pre>"; 
  print_r($array_list); 
echo "<pre>";

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_multisort`

[MANUAL](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

try this:

```
$upload = array();
foreach ($load_image_array as $key => $row)
{
    $upload[$key] = $row['upload_id'];
}
array_multisort($upload, SORT_DESC, $load_image_array);
```

Comment: i tried as you said, something like this : $upload = array();
foreach ($load_image_array as $key)
{
  foreach($key as $k => $v) 
  {
    $upload[$k] = $v['upload_id'];
  }
    
}
array_multisort($upload, SORT_DESC, $load_image_array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($upload);
echo "</pre>"; but it just show : Array
(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => 24
    [2] => 22
) It should be 4 element and it just return 3 of it.

Comment: try to copy my code because you have write other code, try mine code exactly it works @Chivaa

Comment: I added some codes because it's showing : Message: Undefined index: upload_id at the line $upload[$key] = $row['upload_id']; . @ Alessandro Minoccheri